# Fine-Uploader Replace File but keep UUID

Tags: javascript, fine-uploader

Does Fine-Uploader have the concept of replacing an existing file, but keeping the same UUID?

My uploaders are restricted to one file only.  When clicking upload file again (after a file has already been successfully uploaded) results in a new UUID created for the new file.  I'd like to keep the same UUID since it may already be cross linked to other data points in our back end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing a UUID for multiple files defeats the entire purpose of a UUID. So this is not supported.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same use case and did not find a direct solution. The easiest solution for me was to handle the [onSubmit](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/events.html#submit) event and change the UUID to a value that you create in your back end.

```
var sameUuid = qq.getUniqueId();
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    callbacks: {
        onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {
            this.setUuid(id, sameUuid);
        }
    }
});
```

You could also generate a second UUID that does not change and send it along as a [parameter](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.params) or as a [custom header](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/options.html#request.customHeaders).